# Symfony anchor path no integer allowed?

Tags: php, symfony

When I try to run the following code and see what it looks like in the browser:

`<a href="{{ path('movies', {'pageNumber': 1}) }}" class="active">{{ currentPage }}</a>`

This would render:

`<a href="/app_dev.php/movies" class="active">1</a>`

It looks like integers cannot be passed in the path variable of a Twig Template like this (goal:

`<a href="/app_dev.php/movies/1" class="active">1</a>`

)?

When I enter

`<a href="{{ path('movies', {'pageNumber': 'foo'}) }}" class="active">{{ currentPage }}</a>`

it renders `<a href="/app_dev.php/movies/foo" class="active">1</a>`

So the last example works perfectly fine but whenever I make use of an integer it doesn't work? Am I doing something wrong?

Routing:

```
movies:
    path:     /movies/{pageNumber}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:MovieDisplay:show, pageNumber: 1 }
```

Method:

```
public function showAction(Request $request, $pageNumber)
{
    //some code here...

    return $this->render('movies/index.html.twig', array(
    //some other parameters here
    'pageNumber' => $pageNumber
    ));
}
```

Thanks in advannce.

Comment: You might want to add your routing annotaton / configuration. Also: try passing integers without the quotation marks, eg: `{'pageNumber': 1}` instead of `{'pageNumber': '1'}`

Comment: can you please post your routing information?

Comment: Updated my question, might want to take a look now, pardon me.

Comment: Don't know of the top of my head, but it could be that default values are omitted if passed (since they aren't neccesary). Did you try any other integer than `1`? See [the Symfony Docs on placeholders](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/routing.html#required-and-optional-placeholders) aswell.

Comment: Ah yes I think you're right haha how lame of me, thanks.